# ESP8266/NodeMCU unable to communicate with MFRC522 RFID reader

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, rfid

I am trying to use the 'DumpInfo.ino' example file to dump an rfid tag, the only changes i have made to the example is changing the pin settings.

```
#define RST_PIN         3          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          4         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
```

i have wired it based on [this guide](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/ESP8266-MFRC522) (tried using the pins shown on here as well) when i run the code i get this error from `mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();`

```
WARNING: Communication failure, is the MFRC522 properly connected?
```

Ive also tried printing the version and i get 0xFF which along with 0x00 seems to mean it isnt connected.

The only light that is on during the test is D1 on the RFID reader which you can see in the first wiring pic.

[Pictures of wiring here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D1hD.jpg)

Edit: I've changed the pins to D3 and D4 but i still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the pins to Dx constants, to match your connections

```
#define RST_PIN         D3         
#define SS_PIN          D4
```

because pin D3 is not io 3 and pin D4 is not io 4. see [pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/variants/nodemcu/pins_arduino.h)

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realise that, unfortunately it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it working with this pinlayout:

D1 (GPIO 5)-- RC522 - RST

D2 (GPIO 4)-- RC522 - SDA/SS

D3 (GPIO 0)

D5 (GPIO 14)-- RC522 - SCK

D6 (GPIO 12)-- RC522 - MISO

D7 (GPIO 13)-- RC522 - MOSI

D8 (GPIO 15)

also i used this tutorials code and i posted a serial.println after each piece of code to see where it is/or fails:
http://www.instructables.com/id/MFRC522-RFID-Reader-Interfaced-With-NodeMCU/